# how to get 8 characters in a string after joining two words in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i need to get first 8 characters after replacing whitespaces of a two string example "united states of america" by find and replace removed whitespaces "unitedstatesofamerica" but i need string upto length of 8 after removing whitespaces ie "unitedst" pls help me

Comment: please make an attempt at solving the issue and share what code you have and what is not working

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want `substr()`:

```
select substr(replace(col, ' ', ''), 1, 8)
```

Comment: i got it... jus crct me for this query as i am new to this developing side  if abc = substr( replace("abc", " " , ""),1,8)  then tempvalue=abc  for the above query will it work ?

Comment: @ABS . . . This returns up to the first 8 characters in a string.  If there are fewer, then fewer are returned.  Do note, though, that double quotes are not generally string delimiters in SQL.  Single quotes are used for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `[[:space:]]` POSIX within `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function in order to remove all whitespace characters including non-printable ones such as

```
SELECT SUBSTR( REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'[[:space:]]'), 1, 8) AS col
  FROM t -- your original table
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4ce4e97e4b283e7b9deaccff4a12c81e)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove all whitespaces (spaces, tabs, line breaks) then you want to use a regular expression to replace the whitespaces and then you can use `SUBSTR` to find the first 8 characters:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '\s+'), 1, 8)
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( col ) AS
SELECT 'United States of America' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A B' || CHR(9) || 'C' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) || 'D E F G H I J K L M' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(COL,'\S+'),1,8) |
> | :------------------------------------ |
> | UnitedSt                              |
> | ABCDEFGH                              |
> | ABCDEFGH                              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9072180760dcea69efb1e32477240233)*